# insert_cols - specify name in python/openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

In the code below, I insert a column into a specified excel sheet. But it is inserting a column without a name. How do I add a name to this column, I couldnt find a way online to give a name to this column?

```
    import openpyxl
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
    
    # X = input(str("Enter File Name: "))
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Price")
    #insert new column#insert new column
    column_count = sheet.max_column
    print(x)
    x = int(column_count)
    sheet.insert_cols(x-1,1)
    
    print(x)
    wb.save('inv.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openpyxl documentation says how to name a range:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html#creating-new-named-ranges

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange', attr_text='Sheet!$A$1:$A$5')
wb.defined_names.append(new_range)
```